# Why is my NPM cache folder in ./false/_cacache?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-cache

I am on an NPM project using Docker, PhpStorm, VS Code and runs locally and through Docker.

Under which circumstances is this folder put into `./false/`? Has anyone encountered this in the past and would share what they found out?

```
project-root-dir
|__ false
   |__ _cacache
      |__ <hash>
|__ node_modules
|__ Dockerfile
|__ main.js
|__ package.json
```

I suspect this line is creating the folder `_cacache` folder inside `false`:

```
FROM node:12

# ...

# Some directory is missing at this point and results in `false` ?
RUN npm install -g npm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the NPM configuration for `cache` has been set to `false` somewhere. You might expect that to disable caching, but [`cache`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-cache#cache) is expecting a *string*, the path to the cache directory.

In this case it's because you ran with `--no-cache`; anything you pass as `--no-<name>` sets the config of `<name>` to `false`.